# Resolve issue : Import "rest_framework" could not be resolved

Tags: django-rest-framework

so I am working to integrate a react app with django.
But having this issue with #djangorestframework

Import "rest_framework" could not be resolved:

Pipfile.lock
[pipfile.lock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnhpB.png)

serializer.py
[serializer.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goqt3.png)

views.py
[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhzle.png)

Below is the error in terminal:
IDE used :VScode
[Terminal screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWJZU.png)

Note:I did the whole setup of the project using gitbash and created a virtual environment for the project using pipenv

output of pip freeze
[pip freeze output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MysYM.png)

1.I tried to re-install djangorestframework in vscode

2.I declared it under INSTALLED_APPS[
'rest_framework'
]

3. I wrote a script to make sure the interaction of django with other apps in seetings.py
   [in seetings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bevL9.png)

[settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZYZH.png)

Comment: Are you sure about installing djangorestframework because I cannot see it on your pip freeze output?

Answer (score 0):

In the pip freeze output, it appears you have not installed Django rest framework.

Activate the shell by running `pipenv shell`, and install Django rest framework with `pipenv install djangorestframework`.